# Is it possible to use getLocaleDateFormat in Angular5 webapp

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have imported the `CommonModule`, set the locale using angular-cli and now want to use the locale settings from the injected `@angular/common/locales/` file. 
When I call `getLocaleDateFormat()` (from the local_data_api) the next error is thrown:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '@angular/common/src/i18n/locale_data_api' in ...

I suppect this is because the local_data_api is private. It there another way to use the locale settings?

Answer (score 0):

try importing from @angular/common.

Comment: I already did (import { getLocaleDateFormat } from '@angular/common';)